# Share contact via sms using nativescript

Tags: nativescript

How can. share a contact details using nativescript? I want to send it through SMS and email if possible.

I am already using the contacts plugin and I looked into the social share plugin but I didn't find any useful information on how to do it.

https://github.com/firescript/nativescript-contacts

https://github.com/tjvantoll/nativescript-social-share

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The social share plugin allows the user to pick an app to share with; you can't (at this point) target a specific app with that plugin.

If you want to directly share to email you can use the Email plugin: https://github.com/eddyverbruggen/nativescript-email .. it allows you to open an email draft with everything prefilled. The only thing the user needs to do is press 'send' (or pick a different 'from' account).

For sharing directly to SMS you can take a look at this plugin: https://github.com/firescript/nativescript-messenger